# YAML Beans reading nested objects

Tags: java, mongodb, yaml

I have a YAML file in this format:

```
MongoDB:
       - server:
          - host: localhost:27017
          - minOplogHours: 100
          - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
       - server:
          - host: localhost:27018
          - minOplogHours: 100
          - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
       - server:
          - host: localhost:27019
          - minOplogHours: 100
          - maxSecondaryDelay: 120
```

I need to be able to access the data from each of the `host:` fields for each `server:` how can I achieve this?

so far I have this:

```
  YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("src/mongodb.yml"));
  Object object = reader.read();

  Map resultMap = (Map) object;
  System.out.println(resultMap.get("MongoDB"));
```

which prints:

```
[{server=[{host=localhost:27017}, {minOplogHours=100}, {maxSecondaryDelay=120}]}, {server=[{host=localhost:27018}, {minOplogHours=100}, {maxSecondaryDelay=120}]}, {server=[{host=localhost:27019}, {minOplogHours=100}, {maxSecondaryDelay=120}]}]
```

how can extract the server details from this string? more specifically how can i get `host:` values.

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old post but I don't see any response. Here is what I think will work for you.

Replace

```
Map resultMap = (Map) object;
```

with

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> resultMap = (Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>) object;
```

I have had something like this and it worked. 
I hope this might help someone.

Comment: Hi, suppose if the server are names as 1, 2, 3, ten how can i get MongoDB/server1/host.
will this work: resultMap.get("MongoDB.server1.host")    ?